# Error on gulp-uglify installation with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am new in nodejs and also gulp. I am going to start with node and gulp for some advancement in my development skills.

All thing are going good when installing the node js and gulp. I am checking both of this with checking there version on command prompt.
Here's the command:

```
node -v // for node version
npm -v // for npm
```

And installing the gulp with npm using command.

```
npm install -g gulp // gulp global

npm install --save-dev gulp // gulp in my project
```

After these steps, i am going to install gulp uglify.

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-uglify
```

Here's i am receiving the error. But i am not able to understand this error.

[image: Error screenshot]

And also the path shown in command prompt for npm-debug.log. Here no file generated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should start the installation when in the STATIC directory

```
 (ReactEnv) C:\Users\LUCKYPIUS\Desktop\REACT&DJANGO\APP\Reactify\static>
```

Do this first!

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Still in the same static directory, run this..

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-uglify
```

It should be able to locate the previous files and install successfully.(meanwhile always use a virtual enviroment for your projects).
Goodluck.